# Maven: filtering seam components.xml in target directory

Tags: maven

I'm trying to convert an Ant project to Maven. The existing build uses Ant-style properties in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/components.xml`, which is a Seam file.

I'm able to get the properties expanded in the actual resulting `war` file, via the maven-war-plugin. But I can't seem to get the properties expanded in `target/myproject/WEB-INF/components.xml`.

This means that when I try to run the Jetty plugin, it doesn't see the expanded properties.

I tried defining the properties in both an external file, and also right in the build. My profile section looks like the following:

```
  <profiles>
      <profile>
          <id>dev</id>

          <activation>
              <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
          </activation>

          <build>
              <filters>
                  <filter>src/main/filters/components-dev.properties</filter>
              </filters>
          </build>

        <properties>
            <debug>true</debug>
            <jndiPattern>FOO</jndiPattern>
        </properties>

       </profile>
  </profiles>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run `mvn jetty:run` it executes the lifecycle up through `test-compile`.  The web resources don't get filtered until the war plugin runs as part of `package`.  I found a  [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475811/who-to-filter-resources-when-using-maven-jetty-plugin) that seems similar, does that solution work for you?